# SpringBoot RestController not recognizing spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy property

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I have a SpringBoot (2.5.x) RestController which is returning Lists and would like to force the JSON representation to use specific naming convention for the properties.  I've tried the spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy property in application.properties but it seems to have no effect.  Also tried custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, using setPropertyNamingStrategy on the Autowired objectMapper, and using the @JsonNaming annotation in the controller class.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

--john

Comment: can you show what json you want to get ? and your classes, I think putting a reproducer in github is best :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the class

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

But it is outdated

At the same time it is still available

I don't know why

my spring boot 2.5.4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming
    
    @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    class Facility {
        String facility
        String facilityCode
        Integer sampleCount
    }
```